# kendo UI window z-index

Tags: kendo-ui

how can I remove z-index of the kendo window? I don`t want window to be modal, so I did like this **.Modal(false)**. **But of no use , window is rendering with z-index of 10003** like a popup. My intention is to **render 9 windows on a same page ,put 3 windows per row in a table.** Because of z-index , layout is distracting. If I can able to remove z-index, I can succeed.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
.Name("window")
.Title("About Alvar Aalto")
```

### .Modal(false)

```
.Content(@<text>
    <div class="armchair">
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/content/web/window/armchair-402.png")"
                alt="Artek Alvar Aalto - Armchair 402" />
        Artek Alvar Aalto - Armchair 402
    </div>

    <p>
        Alvar Aalto is one of the greatest names in modern architecture and design.
        Glassblowers at the iittala factory still meticulously handcraft the legendary
        vases that are variations on one theme, fluid organic shapes that let the end user
        ecide the use. Interpretations of the shape in new colors and materials add to the
        growing Alvar Aalto Collection that remains true to his original design.
    </p>       
</text>)
.Draggable()
.Resizable()
.Width(600)
.Actions(actions => actions.Pin().Minimize().Maximize().Close())

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this can be done with the available configuration options. You could try using `.Visible(false)` and then manually adjust the z-index for each window to make it visible, but I imagine this would be brittle.

So I would recommend extending the window widget to create your own window type which doesn't manipulate the z-index in this way; this would keep your code encapsulated in its own class. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19202323/2001735) for some more information regarding extending kendoWindow (and a simple example). As far as I can see, the main method responsible for the z-index behavior is [window.toFront()](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/window#methods-toFront), so you'd probably have to rewrite that.

Comment: I did some research in kendo UI forum, I couldn`t able to find good article regarding rewriting window.toFront() method. can you advice me on this .

Comment: @user2957871 What do you need advice on? You basically need to look at the source code for kendoWindow and adjust the code that sets the z-index; you may not find an article for that because it involves some custom development and that's not part of what Telerik offers in terms of support.

Answer (score 1):

Since you plan to render the windows in a 3 by 3 grid I guess that you don't want to move or resize them and what you need from a KendoUI window is just the styling, correct? If so, you should take a look into panels styling (see KendoUI demo [here](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/styling/panels.html)) where you can style your code as a KendoUI window but, of course, you can neither move, nor hide nor resize.

You just need to use the following HTML:

```
<div class="k-block"><div class="k-header">Header</div>Block with header</div>
```

Comment: Hi OnaBai, thanks for your input. I want to resize and move windows too.

Answer (score 1):

the z-index is set on the "style" property dynamically of the div.

with css all you need is an !important rule that will override styles defined on the element.

```
  #mycontainer .k-window{
        z-index: 3 !important;
  }
```

Comment: This may be happening dynamically though.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is dynamic.  Kendo doesn't define !important rules.  so this one rule should always win.

Comment: This does not work for me. I have 3 popup windows; z-index is dynamically set on first two; I manually set the second popup to 30000 which is way higher than the dynamically assigned z-indexes, but after I pop up the third window, and close it, the second goes BEHIND the first one; I check the z-index and 30,000 is not assigned.  Used the code you have above except for 30000 on z-index.  ToFront does not work either.